# PostgresQL: Loop over integer[] and insert current element into another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops

I have a function which takes a parameter named `p_categories`, of type `smallint[]`.

How do I look through `p_categories` and execute the following command, where `cat` is the current `smallint` in `p_categories`?

```
INSERT INTO mytable (i_category) VALUES (cat)
```

Something like this (*pseudocode*) maybe?

```
FOR cat in SELECT p_categories
    INSERT INTO mytable (i_category) VALUES (cat)
END LOOP;
```

That gives me an error: "invalid input syntax for integer: "{14,20}" when `p_categories` is `'{14,20}'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`unnest`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html)

```
INSERT INTO mytable (i_category)
SELECT unnest(p_categories);
```

The `unnest` array function just expands an array into its elements.

Or a more concrete example:

```
> create table t (i int not null);
> insert into t (i) select unnest(array[1,2]);
> select * from t;
 i 
---
 1
 2
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Could you please be more complete with your example? Replacing the "INSERT INTO" statement with your code is not working. Thanks! :)

Comment: @PostgresQLNewb: Are you sure that `cat` is an array of integers and that it hasn't been converted to a string somewhere along the way?

Comment: Ahh, you meant unnest(p_categories), not unnest(cat).

Comment: @PostgresQLNewb: Right, sorry I got things a bit mixed up, I'll fix the answer to avoid confusion.